# Code highlighter like on Symfony and Doctrine sites

Tags: php, xml, tabs, yaml, codehighlighter

I really like highlighting and tabs that are used for code snippets on [symfony.com](http://symfony.com/) and [doctrine-project.org](http://doctrine-project.org/) sites.

[image]
[image]

I wish I knew how they managed to achive this. Probably they use some special JavaScript library?

Comment: Have you tried searching Google for syntax highlighters?

Comment: The tabs on these sites its just a nice way of presenting their content. As for the code (syntax) highlighting any decent [PHP IDE](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-ide/index.html) would do the job

Comment: I'm using Google code prettifier now, but in future I want to switch to the above mentioned things.

Comment: Initially though that you're developing in PHP and wanted syntax highlighting for the source code...

Comment: Oh maybe. pankar, your answer is brilliant as I'm using Symfony2 for my project. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/documentation/format.html) online documentation:

> The Symfony2 documentation uses reStructuredText as its markup
>   language and Sphinx for building the output

So go through these tools' documentation to get an idea on how you can adapt them to your site